# AES polynomial binary division

Tags: polynomials

Could some one just explain me how the binary division of this polynomial evalutes to the mentioned ans ?

$$x^{13} + x^{11} + x^{9} + x^8 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 +1 \pmod{x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x +1} \\\equiv x^7 + x^6 + 1$$
If I use binary division the two polynomials are
$10101101111001_b \text{ modulo } 100011011_b$ which does not give me $11000001_b$.  Can any one provide me the steps to achieve the answer? 
I have tried it and I get $0011111111_b$ which is not the expected and not even close to it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you perform polynomial long division, you obtain a remainder $-x^7 - x^6 + 1$

Comment: Show us the first step in your attempt in detail.